# fsck Dirty Bit Reported

Tags: boot, partitioning, fsck

**MY COMPUTER**

-Model: Msi GL72 7QF
-Processor: Intel i7-7700HQ; 2.8GH
-RAM: 16GB DDR4
-GPU: nVidia GTX960M, Optimus enabled
-SSD: 500GB, GPT UEFI
-OS: Windows10 Insider Preview; Mageia 7; Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Secure boot and fast boot are disabled.

---

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.3 and am receiving an error message that Grub cannot install. One of the things I did to troubleshoot was run fsck to examine the ESP partition. This is the results:

```
root@msi:~# fsck /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
1) Remove dirty bit
2) No action
? 2
There are differences between boot sector and its backup.
This is mostly harmless. Differences: (offset:original/backup)
  65:01/00
1) Copy original to backup
2) Copy backup to original
3) No action
? 3
/dev/sda2: 725 files, 16131/76646 clusters
root@msi:~#
```

I chose not to fix anything because I don't know what fsck is telling me. What is a dirty bit and why should I care about it? Also, since I'm having trouble installing Ubuntu, do I really want to rely on the backup boot sector? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

It would mean that at some time during shutdown of your computer, your EFI partition, which is a `vfat` file system, was not properly unmounted. The linux kernel sets the `dirty bit` when mounting and clears it when unmounting.

For now, fix the error by unmounting the device and issuing the command `fsck -a /dev/sda2`. This would repair the volume using default assumptions.

Comment: Thank you for the hint.  That cleared the dirty bit, but I am still getting the error when trying to install Ubuntu/Grub.

Comment: I also get a dirty bit when I try FSCK from the safe mode. When I try your suggestion in the command line, I read "WARNING!!!  The filesystem is mounted.   If you continue you ***WILL***
cause ***SEVERE*** filesystem damage."  What can I do? Thoughts?

Comment: The warning speaks for itself. You may not check a file system that is currently in use.